# Where to ask for a reasoning behind an approach?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a question about an approach used in one of open-source APIs. Namely, an old version significantly differs in approach to the new version, and I don't see any reasoning behind the change. Where should I ask about such reasoning?

I do realise it's on a verge of asking for an opinion, however I don't intend to ask about whether that API change is good or bad.

Edit: as suggested by TZHX, I've checked and yes, the project in question does have a mailing list, so I will direct my question there. However, for future reference, what if there was no known contact with the developers, or if I wanted to ask Stack users for an outside-view answer?

Comment: Do the API maintainers have a mailing list? Any change in approach would probably have been discussed / announced there?

Comment: Yes, they do. Thanks for hinting that, I'm about to write there. However, what if there wasn't one? I've ammended this to the original question.

Comment: If you can distill down the difference in approach between the new and the old version, you might be able to write a good question for [programmers.se]. Though please read their on-topic rules first.

Comment: I agree (I think) with Dedup. Asking about the specific library and the decisions they made is too localised -- but asking for the pros and cons of approach a vs approach b might be made into an acceptable question (though would be at risk of being considered broad and/or opinion based if there isn't a strong technical difference between them or approaches A and B aren't really related in any way)